# How to check if someone is spying on personal wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

[image: Connected computers table]

Question: What is PC_A6FC .... is this a person spying on my router? Or is this normal?

DESKTOP-FTLGQC0 is my computer, both hosts have the same MAC address which is why I am wondering.

Is there a way I can block all computers from entering my network unless it is a certain MAC or IP address?

I have the Rogers Hitron CGN2-ROG wireless router

Any personal advice on how to track if someone is spying or tracking my personal wireless network?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "Any personal advice on how to track if someone is spying or tracking my personal wireless network" Chnage the password.  You ask what PC_A6FC is, we don't know, outside of the fact it's a device that's connected to your network.  Given the fact A6FC exists in the MAC address it's your PCs IPv6 address.  Post your IPv6 address for your desktop (edit your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in that screenshot is most likely just the way your router's admin UI shows you that your PC has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address. Click on the IPv6 Detail button, see what IPv6 address it thinks your PC has, and then verify on your PC that you do indeed have that IPv6 address.

As for why the Host Name is different, it may just be that your PC's DHCPv6 client sends a different Host Name option, or doesn't send it at all. Or maybe your router thought it would be too confusing to see the same host name twice, or its tables couldn't handle more than one entry for the same host name, so your router decided to invent a different host name based on the PC's MAC address, and uses that for the host name field for the IPv6 entry in the table.

So if I were you, *and I knew I had good security enabled with a strong passphrase that hadn't leaked out*, I wouldn't worry about seeing that IPv6 entry in the list.

The best way to secure your wireless network is to do all of the following:

1. Enable pure WPA2-Personal (a.k.a. WPA2-PSK). That is, use only AES-CCMP encryption, not the old TKIP encryption that was part of original WPA and is no longer needed and causes problems.
2. Set a very strong passphrase. Don't accept the default one, or any one that the ISP set for you or that you set by way of the ISP's website.
3. Don't give out the passphrase to anyone. If you must give it to guests sometimes, change it regularly.
4. If your router is from your ISP, make sure you've disabled your ISP's ability to change your router's admin passphrase and wireless passphrase.
5. Make sure your router's admin passphrase is also strong, and unrelated to your wireless passphrase.

If you don't have WPA2 with a strong passphrase, or if you think your passphrase may have gotten compromised (e.g. could in the hands of someone who wants to spy on you), there is no way to tell whether or not someone is spying on your network. You do not have to join a wireless network to spy on it. All you need is a wireless device, in range of the network, set to capture and decode all the traffic on the network. It doesn't have to join the network to do that, so your router wouldn't show it as a connected client.